# PowerShell Nested Group hierarchy to string

Tags: powershell, active-directory, nested

Seeking some help creating a group membership report that has a value for nesting hierarchy.

Input CSV Data

```
distinguishedName
"CN=group1,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Desired Output CSV

```
ParentGroup,Member,AccessGrantedVia,NestingPath
"group1","user1","group3","group1 > group3"
```

In this scenario, user1 is a member of group3. group3 is a member of group1

I can't figure out how to reset and keep track of the nesting levels.

```
function Get-AllGroupMembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $DistinguishedName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]
        $NestedGroups
    )
    
    $userSplat = @{
        ParentGroup = $null
        Member = $null
        AccessGrantedVia = $null
        NestingPath = $null
    }

    $members = Get-ADGroup -Identity $DistinguishedName -Properties members | Select-Object members

    $memberObjects = @()
    foreach ($member in $members.members) {
        $memberObjects += Get-ADObject -Identity $DistinguishedName -Properties * | Select-Object *
    }
   
    foreach ($memberObject in $memberObjects) {
        switch ($memberObject.objectClass) {
            'user' { 
                $userSplat.ParentGroup = $script:ParentGroup
                $userSplat.Member = $memberObject.distinguishedName
                $userSplat.AccessGrantedVia  = $DistinguishedName
                $userSplat.NestingPath = ($NestedGroups -join ' > ')
                $script:Report += $userSplat
            }
            'Group' { 
                $NestedGroups.Add($memberObject.distinguishedName) | Out-Null
                Get-AllGroupMembers -DistinguishedName $memberObject.distinguishedName 
            }
            Default {}
        }
    }
    
}

$Groups = Import-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\groups.csv 
$report = @()
foreach ($group in $Groups) {
    $script:ParentGroup = $group.distinguishedname
    $nestedGroups = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
    $nestedGroups.Add($group.distinguishedName) | Out-Null
    Get-AllGroupMembers -DistinguishedName $group.distinguishedname
}
```

Comment: [This is pretty old](https://github.com/santysq/Get-Hierarchy) and for sure could be improved but might be what you're after

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.